# QML : What is the equivalent of QPainterPath?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qpainterpath

In order to convert one GUI interface written in C++ with the Qt libraries to QML, I've to find an alternative to QPainterPath in QML. Indeed, for now, a bunch of shapes are drawn in the GUI interface and the C++ code modifies the color of those objects when certain events happen. QPainterPath objects are used to store those shapes.

I would appreciate if you can show me how to draw two rectangle objects in a QML canvas and then how to modify their filled color within the C++ code.

Comment: You draw two rectangles by using `Rectangle` instead. You modify the color by changing their `color` property. You don't want to do this from C++ code. You don't want to change QML created objects from C++ code.

Comment: See this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html

Comment: @derM : it's not a choice, I've to modify the color from C++ because I'm interfacing the GUI with ROS. (The color has to be changed when a peculiar message is received). I've to use a Canvas object cause' the shapes I want to draw are way more complex than simple rectangles.

Comment: Instead of downvoting,I'm genuinely wondering why you don't help me with my problem if it's so obvious for you ? @eyllanesc : I couldn't find anything related to what I'm trying to do in the link you posted. Am I missing something ?

Comment: See http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/07/07/let-there-be-shapes/ and http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/08/10/let-there-be-more-shapes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, one option could be Canvas, it has methods similar to QPainterPath. In the next part I will show an example where the color can be changed from C ++ through a method that generates random colors and are called by a QTimer:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QColor>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QTime>
#include <QTimer>

class ColorProvider: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)
public:

    QColor color() const{
        return mColor;
    }
    void setColor(const QColor &color){
        if(color == mColor)
            return;
        mColor = color;
        emit colorChanged(mColor);
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void randomColor(){
        qsrand((uint)QTime::currentTime().msec());
        setColor(QColor(qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256));
    }

signals:
    void colorChanged(const QColor &color);
private:
    QColor mColor;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    ColorProvider obj;

    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &obj, &ColorProvider::randomColor);
    timer.start(100);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("colorProvider", &obj);
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Canvas {
        id:canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPaint:{
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.lineWidth = 4
            ctx.fillStyle = "orange"
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
            ctx.fillRect(50, 40, 100, 100)
            ctx.stroke()
            ctx.fill()

            ctx.lineWidth = 10
            ctx.fillStyle = colorProvider.color
            ctx.fillRect(150, 150, 300, 300)
            ctx.stroke()
            ctx.fill()

            ctx.roundedRect(20, 20, 40, 40, 10, 10)
        }
    }

    Connections {
        target: colorProvider
        onColorChanged: canvas.requestPaint()
    }
}
```

<sup>The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/47569710).</sup>